# Dereferencing an element of an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So recently in class, we were introduced to pointers and heaps and how they work. A question I have is why cant we `cout` a dereferenced pointer in that array? For example, in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double* p = new double[2];
    *(p + 0) = 37.5;
    *(p + 1) = 101.4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << *p[i] << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Why doesn't `cout << *p[i]` work but `cout << *(p + i)` does?

Comment: because `*p[i]` would be equivalent to `*(*(p + i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the name of an array is a pointer to the first element. C++ inherited that from C. In your program, p is the pointer to the first element of the array. So you either do pointer arithmetics as you did when setting the elements (e. g. *(p + 1) = 101.4;) or you use the subscript operator ([]) to do the arithmetics: *(p + i) is the same as p[i]. The compiler translates p[i] to 1) adding i to p and then 2) access the address that resulted from the sum. That is exactly what you have written: *(p + 1). The statement in the parentheses is calculated first and the reference operator is applied to this result. That is exactly what happens if you use the index operator instead. So your loop has to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Because of the precedence of operators your statement *p[i] translates to *(p[i]). So this statement tries to use the double read from the array as an address that shall be accessed. That this is not possible, is obvious (hopefully).

Got it?

P.S.: And please, do yourself a favor and ALWAYS surround the body of for/while/if statements with curly brackets. That saves you a LOT of time (especially debugging your own nonsense). Trust me, it is true.

Comment: "In C, the name of an array is a pointer to the first element" that is not correct.

Comment: Ahh I understand now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << p[i];
```

should work as you expect
because `*p[i]` basically is `*(*(p + i))`

read here for me https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8a-pointer-arithmetic-and-array-indexing/

Comment: References alone are not enough to constitute an answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It's assumed the author finished writing his answer when he chooses to post it.

Comment: Sure, but my last comment wasn't meant to discourage edits. It's meant to point out that the "I wasn't done" defense shouldn't apply to SO answers.

Comment: @inxoy, there is no way to tell whether you have completed your answer or you are still working on improving it.

Answer (score 0):

`p[1] = *(p + 1)` 
it is what you want to do. The [] operator already dereferences.
`*p[1] =  *(*(p + 1))`
it tries to dereference a double Wich cannot happen

Comment: Not quite, due to operator precedence: `*p[1]` is `*(*(p + 1))` those inner parentheses are required

Answer (score -1):

Note that p[i] is same as *(p+i).
Now *p[i] is meaningless, unless p[i] itself points to a different location, for e.g.

```
int t=0;

for(int i = 0; i < 2 ;i++)
   p[i] = &t;

cout << *p[i] << "is nothing but value of t" << endl;
```

I hope it is clear.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense (and won't compile) unless you changed the type of `p` (in which case you need to expand the sample to be complete)